# batch - Script for filesize in GB for a specific folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, filesize

I'm trying to make a batch script that counts the filesize in GB of a specific folder. The folder can be over 2GB. I tried this:

```
@echo off
set size=0
for /r %%x in (folder directory\*) do set /a size+=%%~zx
echo %size% GigaBytes
pause
```

But this always returns zero and is limited to 2GiB.

Then I tried this:

```
@For /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('"dir %1 /s /-c | find "bytes" | find /v "free""') do @Set summaryout=%%a
@For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=)" %%a in ("%summaryout%") do @set filesout=%%a&set sizeout=%%b
@Set sizeout=%sizeout:bytes=%
@Set sizeout=%sizeout: =%
@Echo Size is :%sizeout%
pause
```

But I have no clue how to define a directory and how to set the measurement unit in GB.

PowerShell isn't an option either because this has to run on W2k systems that don't have it.

Comment: `for /r %%x in (folder directory\*) do` should read `for /R "folder directory" %%x in (*) do`. To overcome the 2 GiB limitation you'll have to borrow from another language (like [tag:javascript], [tag:vbscript])…

Comment: @aschipfl that works but how can I convert it to GB?

Comment: Well, if you're talking about the SI-prefix Giga, meaning 1000 * 1000 * 1000, you could remove the last 9 decimal digits of the file sizes, resulting in a GB value rounded downwards (if you check the 9 removed digits in advance, you could do a different type of rounding); if you're talking about the binary prefix Gibi, meaning 1024 * 1024 * 1024, it is going to be hardly possible with batch…

Comment: Windows 2000 reached end-of-support 10+ years ago. There are not even security updates. https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/windowsserver/2010/01/14/windows-2000-server-approaching-end-of-life/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the help of a little vbscript !

```bat
@echo off
Title Script For Getting Folder Sizes
echo Getting folder sizes for you...
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
Set "VBS=%Temp%\ConvertSize.vbs"
set "folder=%~1"
if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"
@for /d %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
    set "size=0"
    @for /f "tokens=3,5" %%b in (
        'dir /-c /a /w /s "%%~fa\*" 2^>nul ^| findstr /b /c:"  "'
    ) do (
        if "%%~c"=="" set "size=%%~b"
    )
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    call :ConvertBytes !size! unit 
    echo(%%~nxa ==^> !unit!
    endlocal 
)
endlocal
pause
exit /b
::-------------------------------------------------------
:ConvertBytes <Size> <Unit>
(
    echo wscript.echo Convert("%~1"^)
    echo 'Function to format a number into typical size scales
    echo Function Convert(iSize^)
    echo    aLabel = Array("bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"^)
    echo    For i = 0 to 4
    echo        If iSize ^> 1024 Then
    echo            iSize = iSize / 1024
    echo        Else
    echo            Exit For
    echo        End If
    echo    Next
    echo    Convert = Round(iSize,2^) ^& " " ^& aLabel(i^)
    echo End Function
)>"%VBS%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Cscript //NoLogo "%VBS%"') do ( set "%2=%%a" )
Exit /b
::-------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify WSH usage with the embedded `mshta.exe` utility.  So I got this code:

```
set "folder=C:\\Folder directory"
@for /f "usebackq " %%a in (`mshta "javascript:var size=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetFolder('%folder%').Size ; new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(size/1073741824);close()"`) do @echo %%a
```

P.S. Folder-path variable must have double slashes (or backslashes). And 1GB size equals `1073741824` bytes.

P.S.S. The utility was already in W2K SP4.